# What happens when the RAM is over in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management, virtual-memory

I'm no computer expert, so let me try to put this question a little bit more specifically:

I do some scientific computations, and the calculations sometimes requires a lot of memory to store their results. A few days ago, I'd an output file that took 4 GB in hard disk, but I have this amount of RAM. So:

- How does the CLR (or is it something else?) deals with the memory when the program you're running allocates more memory than that available in the computer? Does it create some swap in the HD? (I know that could slow down my program, but I'm only interest in the memory issue)
- Is it OS-dependent, say if I work with MONO on linux or with VS on Windows?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A side note, but you can save a 4GB file, without having to have all 4GB in memory.  File stream implementations typically have an intermediate writing buffer which is periodically flushed to the underlying disk as you write to the stream.

Comment: Actually, I was trying to figure out some way to deal with this "big file" problem... My idea was to split the output file in minor files of, say 100 MB. Stream could be useful, but that's for another question, and thanks for the note!

Comment: As long as you're using a reasonably modern OS, I believe the OS file system will allow very large files and take care of all the 'chunking' internally.  Some tools will have problems working with very large files, but the files themselves should store fine.  All of this is independent of memory consumption, which is only an issue if you need to keep a lot of memory around for calculations while writing the file, for instance.  Are you actually encountering problems or is this more just consideration of possible issues?

Comment: Actually, it is just a consideration, along with a problem analysing those files...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The way I find helpful to think about it is: *memory* is disk space. *RAM* is a fast cache. Rather than thinking "when I'm out of RAM, the system will swap it to disk", I think "when I have available RAM, the system will move my on-disk memory into it".

That's backwards from how most people think about it, but I find it helps. RAM is just a performance optimization; the real limit on how much memory you can allocate is available disk space.

Of course it is more complicated than that. On 32 bit operating systems every process gets a 2 billion byte *user address space*. (And the same for the kernel address space, but let's ignore that.) Every page of memory you can access, whether it is in RAM or on disk, has to be in that address space.  You can have more than 2 billion bytes allocated, no problem. But you can only address 2 GB of it at a time. If you have 10 GB allocated, then at least 8GB of it will not be mapped into address space. In that case you have to *unmap* something else and then map what you want into the address space in order to get at it.

Moreover, lots of things need to be in *contiguous* address space. If you have a 1MB stack, for example, then there needs to be a million *contiguous* bytes available in the address space.

When people "run out of memory" they are not running out of RAM; RAM is just a fast cache over the disk. And they are not running out of disk space; there's plenty of that. They're almost always in a situation where there is insufficient contiguous address space to meet the demand.

The CLR memory manager does not implement these fancy map-and-unmap strategies for you; basically, you get your 2GB address space and that's it. If you want to do something fancy, say with memory mapped files, that's up to you to write the code to manage the memory yourself.

Comment: The mapping and unmapping sounds interesting. Can you post a link for how to use it in C++?

Comment: When you said "The CLR memory manager does not implement these fancy map-and-unmap strategies for you", why? I never had to deal with that, so is it because these can not be implemented in a generic, one-size-fits-all way? Just curious :O

Comment: @Joan: Because it is a really hard problem to know what can efficiently be mapped in and out. Suppose you want to have a 10GB video file in memory to edit it. The author of the editing software can know "OK, the file is laid out like this, so let's map so many seconds of the video into address space and unmap the seconds that we are not editing right now". The CLR doesn't have that sort of understanding of what portions of memory are likely to be accessed soon and which are not.

Comment: Thanks Eric, I see what you mean. Definitely sounds like a hard problem.

Answer (score 3):

If you allocate more memory than physically exists, yes, swap space will be used.

If you allocated more memory than can be addressable, an `OutOfMemoryException` will occur.

Not sure about Mono, but I would guess that this is runtime dependent and would behave pretty much the same way (not enough physical memory will cause swapping, too much allocated would cause the exception).

Comment: Sorry, what you mean by addressable? tks

Comment: @Girardi: Basically, your app asks for 6Gb but your machine only has 1Gb, you'll get an [OutOfMemoryException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.outofmemoryexception.aspx).

Comment: @Sergio - not quite right. A 32 bit OS has an address space of 2^32 bits (around 4 GB) - if you try to allocate more than what a process can handle, you will get an OOM exception. For 64 bit OSes this is much larger. If you only have 1GB of memory on a 32 bit OS and try to use 3GB, virtual memory will be used - that is disk swapping will occur.

Comment: @Sergio: That's not necessarily true. You can theoretically use more memory than your machine has physically available. The limitation is how much memory your operating system can use. For example, under 32-bit versions of Windows, a maximum 2 GB of memory is available for user-mode applications. No memory beyond that is addressable, or usable, by your application. In a 64-bit world, that limit is raised substantially.

Comment: @Oded: So if you try to address more memory than your OS can handle you'll get this exception, correct?

Comment: @Girardi - minus what the OS and the other processes on the system require.

Comment: @Sergio - Yes. If you hit the limit and try to allocate more than that - boom.

Answer (score 3):

The run-time just asks the operating system for more memory. The operating system handles paging the existing contents of memory out to disk and otherwise swapping things around to create more free physical memory, if necessary. The same thing happens here for managed C#/.NET programs as happens for regular, unmanaged programs.

The only difference in the world of managed applications is that the .NET run-time imposes some memory overhead, thus limiting the total amount of memory that is actually available for your application. For example, the garbage collector requires some memory space to do its work.

So yes, it's OS-dependent, at least to some extent. However, most modern operating systems have fairly similar approaches to memory management.